# Electron Forge v6, Keytar & Node-Loader Error "no suitable image found... file too short"

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-forge, keytar

I am having some trouble getting the [Keytar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keytar) package working in an Electron Forge v6 project (beta.54).

In a freshly generated project, I receive an error about "file too short" when I run the application. Below is an excerpt of the error dialog shown originating from the main process:

```js
> electron-forge start

✔ Checking your system
✔ Locating Application
✔ Preparing native dependencies: 1 / 1
✔ Compiling Main Process Code
✔ Launch Dev Servers
✔ Compiling Preload Scripts
✔ Launching Application


Webpack Output Available: http://localhost:9000

App threw an error during load
Error: node-loader:
Error: dlopen(/Users/abc/Desktop/app2/.webpack/main/9e6f9bf6669542cb15efba32c033f3de.node, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/abc/Desktop/app2/.webpack/main/9e6f9bf6669542cb15efba32c033f3de.node: file too short
    /Users/abc/Desktop/app2/.webpack/main/9e6f9bf6669542cb15efba32c033f3de.node: file too short
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/abc/Desktop/app2/.webpack/main/index.js:1015:9)
    at Object../node_modules/keytar/build/Release/keytar.node (/Users/abc/Desktop/app2/.webpack/main/index.js:1018:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/abc/Desktop/app2/.webpack/main/index.js:21:30)
    at Object../node_modules/keytar/lib/keytar.js (/Users/abc/Desktop/app2/.webpack/main/index.js:1029:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/abc/Desktop/app2/.webpack/main/index.js:21:30)
    at Object../src/index.ts (/Users/abc/Desktop/app2/.webpack/main/index.js:1440:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/abc/Desktop/app2/.webpack/main/index.js:21:30)
    at /Users/abc/Desktop/app2/.webpack/main/index.js:85:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/abc/Desktop/app2/.webpack/main/index.js:88:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1152:30)
```

It seems that `node-loader` is having trouble with this package. I cannot decipher what is happening as I can see the package `.node` files are copied into `./webpack/main/native_modules` , but there is a hashed filename at the root which seems to import the native file.

One strange thing I *did* notice is that the hashed file at `.webpack/main/9e6f9bf6669542cb15efba32c033f3de.node` contains the following and not the native binary data:

```js
module.exports = __non_webpack_require__("./native_modules/build/Release/keytar.node")
```

Subsequently... these `.node` files `/native_modules/build/Release/keytar.node` *are* what I expect.

How should one proceed? I didn't rush to open issues on GitHub until I figured where the issue was coming from.

I feel at the root, there's an issue with how the `.node` file is generated in `keytar`, but then who even knows what black magic is happening with Webpack and the loaders.

## Steps to reproduce

1. Create a new Electron Forge project `npx create-electron-app app2 --template=typescript-webpack
2. Install Keytar `npm install keytar`
3. Add `const key tar = require('keytar');` into `src/index.ts`
4. Run the app via `npm run start`
5. Experience the error

## Versions

Node: v14.14.0
NPM: v7.0.13

Package JSON dependencies:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack": "6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@marshallofsound/webpack-asset-relocator-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^4.2.1",
    "electron": "11.0.3",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.14",
    "node-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "keytar": "^7.2.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

I had pretty much exact replica of this issue with native module loading the only difference being that in my case the module was locally built and installed as a part of the project.

Something in the webpack's support for native modules has issues within this configuration and causes this. What did the trick for me was to remove `node-loader` in webpack in `webpack.rules.js`, ie removing this section:

```
-  // Add support for native node modules
-  {
-    test: /\.node$/,
-    use: 'node-loader',
-  },
```

I found this solution and further discussion on the topic from the issue tracker of electron-forge: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/issues/1688